# How to shard file into n-out-of-m redundancy (erasure code e.g. kind of reed solomon)?

Tags: backup, redundancy

How to shard file `file` into *m* files, so it can be recovered with any *n* of them ?

It looks like [Erasure Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erasure_code), preferably "optimal erasure codes". (Example of another application and proposed programming library: "You need erasure code" https://stackoverflow.com/a/28932095 ).
It's like [Reed-Solomon error correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction) (something more flexible than [RAID6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_6)) style of redundancy.

Early findings: I've found `rsbep` so far and [some modification](https://www.thanassis.space/rsbep.html), but they rather seem to be designed toward different use case. I've also found reed-solomon from Linux Kernel ported to userspace [here](https://github.com/tierney/reed-solomon), but it's not the tool for my described purpose.

Example for 3-out-of-6 level of redundancy:

```
split_with_redundancy -n 3 -m 6 input.dat
```

Producing `input.dat.0..5`, so any tree of those files are sufficient for recovery:

```
recover_using_redundancy intput.dat.{0,2,4}
```

I do not care for errors within given file, i.e. I do not need [Forward Error Correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction). I assume that I can rely on having n-out-of-m redundant parts fully correct.

Comment: [par2](https://github.com/Parchive/par2cmdline)

Comment: Just came across: https://github.com/utamaro/rsraid -> need to give it a try as description sounds promising: "You can divide a file into k files and create redundant m files, and can recover the original file from arbitrary k files from these (k+m) files." . Also I've found that many projects (rozofs, ceph...) take use of Intel's Opensource ISA-L library: https://github.com/01org/isa-l , so maybe there is also some tool based on it.

Comment: maybe it's a bit stretch, but one can encrypt file with passphrase, and store it with BananaSplit https://bs.parity.io/ ;)

Answer (score 4):

You would want to look at

https://pypi.org/project/zfec/

This does exactly what you are looking for.
E.g.

```
zfec -k3 -m6 input.dat
```

creates 6 files, 3 of which are necessary to reconstruct the original file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use gfshare for this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/gfshare.7.html

```
apt-get install libgfshare-bin
```

For example, with 2-of-7.

```
gfsplit -n 2 -m 7 myfile.txt
```

Only two shares can be used to reconstruct the file:

```
gfcombine myfile.txt.1 myfile.txt.7
```